How do I add padding for a grid in Line Chart-JS?
I want the point area with a tooltip to not break if the maximum value is reached.
There should be padding/margin in front of the top and bottom gridlines

I use "react-chartjs-2", its my settings for options chart.
export const defaultChartOptions = {
  responsive: true,
  maintainAspectRatio: false,
  legend: {
    display: false,
  },
  layout: {
    padding: {
      left: 0,
      right: 0,
      top: 0,
      bottom: 0,
    },
  },
  scales: {
    x: {
         grid: {
          display: false,
          drawBorder: false,
        },
    },
    y: {
         grid: {
          display: false, 
          drawBorder: false,
        },
    },
   }
};


instead of padding, I have an alternative suggestion for you to add the maximum Y axis using suggestedMax on the Y axis as such suggestedMax: 1.1, with that added your max should be 1.1 and have a bit of gap between your chart and the maximum graph height

I used a similar one before: max: maxValue + adjustMaxValue.
This will solve the problem of clipping the max value (which is dynamic), but it doesn't solve for zero, I can't do: min: -1 because it should always be min: 0
It also doesn't solve  the problem of clipping left and right grid.
